# Move UITableViewController Back to Top by a UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I am trying to create a long UITableView, i would like to have a button that allows users can go back to the top of the table by pressing a button at the bottom of the table. 
May I know how could it do this?

-(IBAction) goUp (id) sender{
????code????
}

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In another way you can call [`scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath%3aatScrollPosition%3aanimated%3a)

Comment: That's a Boolean value that makes the table scroll to the top when the status bar is pressed, not when his button is.

Comment: No it's not - @Mat you were right first time, you can call this to scroll to any row. Check the docs...

Answer (score 2):

UITableView is a UIScrollView subclass, so call setContentOffset:animated: like so:

```
CGPoint topOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[tableView setContentOffset:topOffset animated:YES];
```

Comment: Or you can just use `CGPointZero`

Comment: or - (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated to go to row 0, or any other row.

Comment: @danh you would need to add some bounds checking if you used that method - you would need to account for a situation when this is called when there are no rows

Comment: Yes he would.  Zero rows would be a good reason to hide or disable a scroll to top button.